# DataGridView CSV Table searching

Tags: windows, forms, search, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control that is bound to CSV file. I have created a combobox and a textbox. Comobobox provides a list of columns to be selected and Textbox for searching the text.

This is code I use

```
$rows = Import-Csv $ThisCSV -Header Mark, This 
$table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $rows 
Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview3 -Item $table 
$DataGridView3.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
```

Now I am not sure what I should use in `TextChanged` Event of the Textbox to search for string in `Datagridview`.

Thanks,
Nariman

Comment: Share your code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: $ColNameNow = "Name"
$SrcValue = $TextBox1.text

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $datagridview1.RowCount; $i++)
{
    if ($datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['Name'].Value -eq "$SrcValue")
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Found", "Update", "Ok", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)

        $datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index = $i            
        $datagridview1.CurrentRow = $datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells[0]            
        $datagridview1.SelectedRows[$i]         
    }
}

Comment: don't write your code in comment. it is very difficult to understand. Update question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea.

Set the CurrentCell to the found cell. CurrentRow is read-only, as well as CurrentRow.Index.

```
$datagridview1.CurrentCell = $datagridview1.Rows[$1].Cells[$ColNameNow]
```